# Expression of distribution function

Tags: probability, self-study

I was wondering, maybe somebody could explain to me the approach or show me a solution to this exercise?

Random vector $(\xi,\eta) : (\Omega,F, \mathbb{P}) → \mathbb{R^2}$ has the discrete distribution:
$\\$
$\mathbb{P}(\xi = 0,\eta=0)=1/2,\mathbb{P}(\xi = 1,\eta=0)=\mathbb{P}(\xi = 0,\eta=1)=\mathbb{P}(\xi = 1,\eta=1)=1/6$. Find the expression of distribution function $F_{(\xi,\eta)}(x,y)$

My attempt:

I know that $F_{(\xi,\eta)}(x,y) = \mathbb{P}(\xi\leq x, \eta \leq y).$ In general, this task has 5 cases:[image]

I. $F_{(\xi,\eta)}(x,y) = 0,$ when  $x<0, y<0$;

II. $F_{(\xi,\eta)}(x,y) = 1,$ when $x\geq1, y\geq1$;

III. $F_{(\xi,\eta)}(x,y) = \mathbb{P}(\xi\leq x, \eta \leq y) = \mathbb{P}(\xi=0, \eta \leq 1) = \mathbb{P}(\xi=0) = 4/6$ when $0\leq x<1, y\geq1$;

IV. $F_{(\xi,\eta)}(x,y) = \mathbb{P}(\xi\leq x, \eta \leq y) = \mathbb{P}(\xi\leq 1, \eta = 0) = \mathbb{P}(\eta=0) = 4/6$ when $0\leq y <1, x\geq 1$;

V. $F_{(\xi,\eta)}(x,y) = \mathbb{P}(\xi\leq x, \eta \leq y) = \mathbb{P}(\xi= 0, \eta = 0) = 1/2,$ when $0\leq x <1, 0\leq y<1$.

Maybe somebody can tell me if my solution is correct or where I made a mistake?

Comment: What have you tried? Self-study questions should include what work you've done, or they will likely be closed.

Comment: I uploaded my solution. I don't think that this is a correct solution but maybe you can help me by saying where I made some mistakes? Or maybe this is the correct one. I don't know.

Comment: Your solution is _almost_ correct: check the limits of $x$ and $y$ for region II.